# FTP 501 Server cannot accept arguments

Tags: ftp

I am facing an issue with FTP.I am getting error saying that 501 server cannot accept arguments and 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
I am able to connect to ftp site using command prompt but when i hit ls command in,I am getting 501 issue.

Tried to connect through passive mode but no use.
Able to connect and see the directories over FileZilla.

Please suggest.

Comment: switched to passive mode using 'quote pasv' command

Comment: As the answers in the linked question says, you **cannot** switch to the passive mode using `quote pasv` command. It simply does not work. Windows `ftp.exe` **does not support the passive mode**.

Comment: Thanks for the response and i did my code changes to handle the error.It is fine now